# Cropping and and uploading an image to the server

Tags: android, image, bitmap, crop

I need help on an `Android app` I'm working on.

The app allows the user to select a photo from the `gallery` or the `camera`, then to crop the image and finally to upload the image to the `server`.

To crop the image I used the [uCrop](https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop) library of **yalantis** and to upload the photo to the server I use `Retrofit`.

The problem I have is that I select the `image`, the cropping and then when I go to save it on the `server`, the **ORIGINAL** image is saved and not the cropped image.

Could someone tell me why this happens?

here is my code:

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IImagePickerLister{

    Bitmap bitmap;
    private ImageView imageView;
    Button selectImg,uploadImg;
    EditText imgTitle;
    private  static final int IMAGE = 100;

    private ProgressBar progressBar;


    private static final int CAMERA_ACTION_PICK_REQUEST_CODE = 610;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE = 600;
    public static final int CAMERA_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 611;
    public static final int ONLY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 612;
    public static final int ONLY_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 613;

    private String currentPhotoPath = "";
    private UiHelper uiHelper = new UiHelper();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        selectImg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        uploadImg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        imgTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar_cyclic);

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                if (uiHelper.checkSelfPermissions(this))
                    uiHelper.showImagePickerDialog(this, this);
        });

        uploadImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                validateImage();


            }
        });

    }



    private void validateImage() {



        //find values
        final String regName = imgTitle.getText().toString();
        String image = convertToString();

        //        checking if username is empty
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(regName)) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Seleziona i metodi di pagamento del tuo locale.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        //checking if email is empty

        //checking if password is empty

        //After Validating we register User
        uploadImage(regName, image);



    }


    private String convertToString()
    {


        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP,75,byteArrayOutputStream);


        byte[] imgByte = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(imgByte,Base64.DEFAULT);


    }


    private void uploadImage(String imageNome, String image){

        ApiInterface api = ApiClient.createService(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<Img_Pojo> login = api.uploadImage(imageNome,image);

        login.enqueue(new Callback<Img_Pojo>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Img_Pojo> call, Response<Img_Pojo> response) {

                if(Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getIsSuccess() == 1) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class));

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Informazioni inserite!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }

                 else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response.body().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Img_Pojo> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,t.getLocalizedMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }



    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                uiHelper.showImagePickerDialog(this, this);
            else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                uiHelper.toast(this, "ImageCropper needs Storage access in order to store your profile picture.");
                finish();
            } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                uiHelper.toast(this, "ImageCropper needs Camera access in order to take profile picture.");
                finish();
            } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                uiHelper.toast(this, "ImageCropper needs Camera and Storage access in order to take profile picture.");
                finish();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == ONLY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                uiHelper.showImagePickerDialog(this, this);
            else {
                uiHelper.toast(this, "ImageCropper needs Camera access in order to take profile picture.");
                finish();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == ONLY_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                uiHelper.showImagePickerDialog(this, this);
            else {
                uiHelper.toast(this, "ImageCropper needs Storage access in order to store your profile picture.");
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_ACTION_PICK_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(currentPhotoPath);
            openCropActivity(uri, uri);
        } else if (requestCode == UCrop.REQUEST_CROP && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                Uri uri = UCrop.getOutput(data);
                showImage(uri);
            }
        } else if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            try {
                Uri sourceUri = data.getData();
                File file = getImageFile();
                Uri destinationUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                openCropActivity(sourceUri, destinationUri);
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),sourceUri);

                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                uiHelper.toast(this, "Please select another image");
            }
        }
    }

    private void openImagesDocument() {
        Intent pictureIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        pictureIntent.setType("image/*");
        pictureIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            String[] mimeTypes = new String[]{"image/jpeg", "image/png"};
            pictureIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
        }
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(pictureIntent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    private void showImage(Uri imageUri) {
        try {
            File file;
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                file = FileUtils.getFile(this, imageUri);
            } else {
                file = new File(currentPhotoPath);
            }
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            uiHelper.toast(this, "Please select different profile picture.");
        }
    }



    private void openCamera() {
        Intent pictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File file;
        try {
            file = getImageFile(); // 1
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            uiHelper.toast(this, "Please take another image");
            return;
        }
        Uri uri;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) // 2
            uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID.concat(".provider"), file);
        else
            uri = Uri.fromFile(file); // 3
        pictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri); // 4
        startActivityForResult(pictureIntent, CAMERA_ACTION_PICK_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    private File getImageFile() throws IOException {
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "_";
        File storageDir = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM
                ), "Camera"
        );
        System.out.println(storageDir.getAbsolutePath());
        if (storageDir.exists())
            System.out.println("File exists");
        else
            System.out.println("File not exists");
        File file = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir
        );
        currentPhotoPath = "file:" + file.getAbsolutePath();
        return file;
    }

    private void openCropActivity(Uri sourceUri, Uri destinationUri) {
        UCrop.Options options = new UCrop.Options();
        options.setCropFrameColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent));
        UCrop.of(sourceUri, destinationUri)
                .withMaxResultSize(1080, 540)
                .withAspectRatio(16, 9)
                .start(this);


    }
    @Override
    public void onOptionSelected(ImagePickerEnum imagePickerEnum) {
        if (imagePickerEnum == ImagePickerEnum.FROM_CAMERA)
            openCamera();
        else if (imagePickerEnum == ImagePickerEnum.FROM_GALLERY)
            openImagesDocument();
    }
}
```